# Sudo yum seems to fail on CentOS, but works fine after sudo -i

Tags: centos, yum, sudo

I am currently having some trouble with yum through sudo. For some reason, it does not seem to work:

```
aron@graviton [/var/log]# sudo yum clean all
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload/datetime.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:37)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to
the yum faq at:
  http://wiki.linux.duke.edu/YumFaq
```

The strange thing, however, is that it works fine when I gain root privileges through `sudo -i` first.

Any ideas what might be causing this problem?

Comment: What does it do with `sudo -s` instead of `sudo -i`?

Comment: @Raphink `sudo -i` is not the problem. When executing the command `sudo -s yum clean all`, the problem persists, though.

Comment: @Raphink I deleted my previous comment; I was too quick to assume that  the problem was solved. My bad :)

Comment: Hehe. By `sudo -s`, I meant to do `sudo -s; yum clean all`. Did you try that?

Comment: @Raphink yes, does not work and is a bit 'quirky': it basically puts me in a root-environment, then executes the command when exiting the shell. When I use `sudo -s | yum clean all` (which I think is what you ment), it does not work and waits for me to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this problem has been solved. I have evaded this problem by simply using `sudo -i` but just tried using `sudo` combined with `yum` and it works. I have no idea what solved it, but I assume a package update has implemented a fix for this issue.

For reference sake, here are my current versions:

- Sudo version 1.7.2p1
- Yum version 3.2.22
- Kernel 2.6.18-308.16.1.el5
- CentOS 5.5

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why this question is featured now, but it seems to me that the problem lies with resource limits. You should run `ulimit -v` (and perhaps `ulimit -m` too) and check whether you have any memory limits enforced, as most likely `sudo` (without `-i`) won't clear them.

Comment: this helped me, I've set ulimit -m unlimited and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's lacking something in the environment that root has. Does 'sudo su - -c "yum clean all"' work?

Comment: It seems like sudo - is not working on CentOS. Getting `sudo: '-' requires an argument`. It seems like a missing PATH entry indeed. Besides altering the sudo alias to include the path, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Edited my response, I had the command wrong.

Comment: Actually, have you checked the permissions on those python modules? Does your account have read access to them at least?

Comment: Checked it and yes. The modules are chmodded 0755 and are readable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SELinux is to blame. Is it enabled? Try `getenforce` if you are unsure about that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but nope. Not running SELinux.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `strace` to look what's wrong.